# GCC 4.6.0 build sanity check error

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, build, cygwin

So I"m building GCC 4.6.0 in Cygwin, but I've hit a wall. I try to configure gcc from a build directory on the same level as gcc-4.6.0 directory I get this:

```
configure: error: in `/usr/local/contrib/gcc-build/gcc':
configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details.
make[2]: *** [configure-stage1-gcc] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/contrib/gcc-build'
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/contrib/gcc-build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I checked in the config.log and here's what it says:

```
conftest.c: In function `main':
conftest.c:16: error: `choke' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:16: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)
conftest.c:16: error: parse error before "me"
```

What does this error mean? What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr - First, [there's a Wikia page for this](http://cygwin.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_install_a_newer_version_of_GCC) (just revised it too). If you are trying to build the c++ compiler (typically using "--enable-languages=c,c++") ensure you've installed the *gcc-g++* package! Without it your build will fail in the way you are seeing.**

EDIT 2: I revised that Wikia page after successfully building GCC 4.6.0 (C and C++ targets) a little while ago.

First, your post is a bit old so if you figured it out, please let us know!

What set of instructions are you using to build this? I'm working through this myself using [this wiki page](http://cygwin.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_install_a_newer_version_of_GCC) and I hit the same exact wall. Did you look at the config.log file in the folder you are building in? What's it saying what's going wrong? For me it's missing *ppl_c.h*, which I'm trying to track down now, and I'm also getting a repeated error of "cannot exec 'cc1plus'". Because this is configure some of this might be normal - maybe all of it is (a failed check can simply mean an alternate method will be used). I intend to try 4.3.0 next to see if *that* works and what the config.log looks like in comparison.

EDIT 1: Install gcc-g++! That will clear the *cc1plus* hurdle.

My setup, for the record (Note: my host OS is Windows 7 x64):

The core Cygwin packages I'm using are the most current ones (non-experimental):

```
$ cygcheck -c bash binutils bzip2 gcc-core gcc-java  gzip m4 make unzip zip

Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
bash                 4.1.10-4       OK
binutils             2.20.51-2      OK
bzip2                1.0.6-1        OK
gcc-core             3.4.4-999      OK
gcc-g++              3.4.4-999      OK
gzip                 1.4-1          OK
m4                   1.4.16-1       OK
make                 3.81-2         OK
unzip                6.0-10         OK
zip                  3.0-11         OK
```

The packages I've got for GCC in particular, in the order built and installed:

```
gmp-5.0.2
mpfr-3.0.1
mpc-0.9
gcc-4.6.0 (trying to build "c,c++" targets only)
```

Paths are set correctly (at least per the instructions above):

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
CPATH=/usr/local/include
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem in cygwin. Had more than one version of gcc  viz. gcc and gcc-4. Uninstalled the latter. Problem solved for me!

Answer (score 1):

I am in CentOS 5 and I can't solve the problem with above suggestions. My workaround from Ian Lance Taylor:

```
make all-gcc
make install-gcc
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question.